Ubuntu 22.04 detects pci raid bus, but can't seem to see the raid drive?
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and lspci lists the pci raid controller, but lsblk does not show any disks relating to the raid drive or the raid drive. I'm on an Asus b550 motherboard and there aren't any drivers from the manufacturer, but people report raid working in older ubuntu versions...so there must be some way.
